# Evaluating $\int_0^R k\Big(1+(\frac{r}{a})^2\Big)^p r^2 dr $

Tags: integration

Can someone please integrate the following formula for me.  It looks like it needs to be done in parts:

$$\int_0^R k\Big(1+(\frac{r}{a})^2\Big)^p r^2 dr $$

Comment: The boundaries are  $r$ and 0, and you are integration over $r$ :$dr$ ??

Comment: Is $p$ an integer or is it any real number?

Comment: It's a real number.

Comment: This is an incomplete Beta integral.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the inessential constants, the indefinite integral is

$$\int (1+r^2)^pr^2dr=-\frac12\int(1-u)^pu^{1/2}du=-\frac12B(-r^2;p+1,\frac32)+C,$$ which is of the incomplete Beta type. For arbitrary $p$ (and $R$), there is no closed form.

For integer $p$, it can be handled with the Binomial theorem

$$\int (1+r^2)^pr^2dr=\int\sum_{k=0}^p\binom pkr^{2k+2}dr=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom pk\frac{r^{2k+3}}{2k+3}+C.$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.  The constant 'a' is essential.  How did you factor it out?  How do you factor it back into the solution.

Comment: @DRAirey1 Rescale $r'=r/a$.

Comment: Please, explain it like I'm five (ok, fifteen).  I've rescaled r' = r/a, but I still don't see how I can remove it from the integral and add it back to the final form involving the Beta function (the constants are obvious, but I'm unfamiliar with how r' fits in).

Comment: @DRAirey1 What do you get after the substitution of $r/a$ ?

Comment: I don't get that far.  Let's say r' = r/a.  You've replaced (1 + r^2/a^2) with (1 + r^2).  I don't see how (1 + r^2) can be replaced with (1 + r'^2) and still be the same integral.

Comment: Review how variable substitutions are made in integrals.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I'm short on brain cells at the moment and this isn't a homework assignment.  I'm working on hydrogen gas models of galaxy clusters and I've already pushed about as much as I can into my tiny ape brain.  If money's an issue, I'm happy to pay on a consulting basis, just send me your contact info and how much your time is worth.

Comment: Be serious, $$\int_0^R k\Big(1+\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^2\Big)^p r^2 dr =ka^3\int_0^R \Big(1+\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^2\Big)^p \left(\frac ra\right)^2 d\left(\frac ra\right) $$.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Should this work if p goes negative?  It looks like there's a gamma function inside the beta function and it doesn't seem to like the negative exponent.

Comment: No worries, your integral is finite for all $p$ and there's no "Gamma inside Beta".

Comment: Unfortunately, all the Beta functions I've found are implemented with a Gamma Log function.  Even the Wiki page says that the real part of the exponent must be positive.  Do you have some method of implementing the Incomplete Beta that doesn't involve a factorial of some sort?

Comment: Do not confuse the incomplete and complete functions. I don't see how negative $p$ can be a problem, the integral is well defined. As a last resort, think of numerical integration. The solution can also be expressed in terms of the Hypergeometric function, which may have a wider range of implementations.